# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView"

Tags: java, android, admob, google-play-services

I did a lot of research and this seems to be a common error for many users but for very different reasons. None of which I found worked for me.

I'm getting

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{
[...]/[...].activities.StartActivity}: android.view.InflateException:
Binary XML file line #173: Error inflating class [...].BannerAd
    [...]
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error
inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    [...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
"/data/app/[...]-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/[...]-1,
/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I'm having the newest versions of ADT and SDK packages installed. I copied google-play-services_lib to my workspace and imported it as a Android project. I added it as a library to my app project. I checked everything under "Order and Export".

I'm having a banner_ad.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="[...]" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And a BannerAd.java which I am using:

```
package [...];

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import [...].R;
import [...].general.Settings;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;


public class BannerAd extends LinearLayout {
    public BannerAd(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        if (!Settings.PRO) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mInflater.inflate(R.layout.banner_ad, this, true);

            AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

Could it have something to do with proguard? I have no idea, this is my proguard-project.txt file, however:

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

Any ideas what I could try to fix this?

Edit: Sometimes, I also get such output in the console (but not every time I compile, only sometimes):

```
[2014-07-24 12:49:05 - [...]] Dx 
trouble processing:
[2014-07-24 12:49:05 - [...]] Dx bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)
...while parsing com/google/android/gms/internal/mb.class
...while processing com/google/android/gms/internal/mb.class
[2014-07-24 12:49:05 - [...]] Dx 
trouble processing:
[2014-07-24 12:49:05 - [...]] Dx bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)
...while parsing com/google/android/gms/internal/mc.class
...while processing com/google/android/gms/internal/mc.class
[2014-07-24 12:49:05 - [...]] Dx 
[...]
[Lots of similar warnings here]
[...]
trouble processing:
[2014-07-24 12:49:25 - [...]] Dx bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)
...while parsing com/google/ads/mediation/customevent/CustomEventAdapter$a.class
...while processing com/google/ads/mediation/customevent/CustomEventAdapter$a.class
[2014-07-24 12:49:25 - [...]] Dx 
trouble processing:
[2014-07-24 12:49:25 - [...]] Dx bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)
...while parsing com/google/ads/mediation/customevent/CustomEventServerParameters.class
...while processing com/google/ads/mediation/customevent/CustomEventServerParameters.class
[2014-07-24 12:49:25 - [...]] Dx 2786 warnings
```

Comment: Why dont you disable Proguard and try once ?

Comment: Just found out that I ain't using it anyway. proguard.config=[...] is commented out in project.properties.

Comment: Try to add "xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" this to LinearLayout and remove from AdView. You can refer [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals)

Comment: Does not help either. Check out my edit as well.

Answer (score 5):

This because ProGuard. To safely use ProGuard with Google Mobile Ads, add the following to your ProGuard config:

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
   public *;
}

-keep public class com.google.ads.** {
   public *;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I totally forgot I had enabled it and was chasing the `multidex` believing that was the issue. Added a ProGuard config with the above contents and now everything works fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved my problems by

- installing the newest version of Android SDK Build Tools (didn't
  realize that I did not have them yet)
- switching from Compiler compliance level 1.6 to 1.7 (Window - Preferences - Java - Compiler - Compiler compliance level)

Thanks at everybody.

Comment: your issues is the closest post i have seen to experiencing exactly what I am right now - i already upgraded to the latest stuff, and my compiler compliance level was already set to 1.7... any other ideas?

Comment: I had the same exception than @user1684030, but this answer not solved my problem (the same as @user2163298). I've written the solution that I found in case it could help anyone who has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I did what @user1684030 said (upgraded Android SDK Build Tools; changed compiler to 1.7), but not worked for me. I've written the solution that I found in case it could help anyone with the same problem:

In the step 3 of [Setting Up Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) says:

> In your app project, reference Google Play services library project.
>   See Referencing a Library Project for Eclipse for more information on
>   how to do this.
>
> **Note: You should be referencing a copy of the library that you copied
>   to your development workspace—you should not reference the library
>   directly from the Android SDK directory**.

**Solution: Don't do the copy manually. Instead just check the box in Eclipse that says "Copy projects into workspace"**

I did it so and everything worked again.

Thanks to this StackOverFlow question: [How to fix Google Play Services 2 Library install to Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142496/how-to-fix-google-play-services-2-library-install-to-eclipse) 
(Admob is part of Google Play Services)