# Android - New AdmobApi not working for ads in android

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am working on latest android SDK 23 and trying to add admob ad in my app. so I have followed **[admob guied line](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start)**  and **[video guied](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-7_hYCqjs4)** this too but I am still getting an error

**ERROR**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.adtest/com.android.adtest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.adtest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.android.adtest-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    ... 24 more
```

**I dont know where I am going wrong.**
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Even I am enable to see adView in Graphical layout. it shows gray layout in android.

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="AAA"/>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           ads:adSize="BANNER"
                           ads:adUnitId="MY ID"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I can find `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView` in my .java file but unable to find in .xml file

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.adtest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: please post Your Manifest xml

Comment: Please find manifest.xml

Comment: "MY ID" is just a fake for posting here, isn´t it?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs : yes, Just replacement of my admob id.

Comment: are You sure You got the lates google play service package?

Comment: yes yesterday I have downloaded eclpise Luna & then download SDK for android.

Comment: ok, antoher possible cause: some developers made the mistake that they added both libraries, the old AdMobSDK AND Google Play Service Package...

Comment: no I havent work with android ADMobSdk. only Google Play Service.

Comment: how did You use this library? Have You made an Project from existing source code with the play service package?

Comment: I have Imported existing project of google-play-servise-lib(which was already copied in my /libs folder) and then followed steps of adMob guiedline

Comment: is inside the Google Play Service Project under "Properties->Android" the hook setted to "is Library"?

Comment: yes, isLibrary is checked.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33392069/277345

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/play-migration)

you will need to add some java code to your onCreate() also try to follow the steps one by one in the right column

```
// Java code required.
// testDevices and loadAdOnCreate attributes are
// no longer available.
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
.build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: do you have the Google play service lib in the same workspace of your application?

Comment: yes. I have copied that. and imported that from same folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild the app if you copy the code from one project to another

On menu Android Studio > click **Build**> **Rebuild Project**