# The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.android.gms.ads

Tags: java, android, admob, google-play-services

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-32763440xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

When I add this code in the Graphical Layout turns out this error and does not install the application on the device. How can I solve this problem?

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
  - com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
  See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(    at            java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(    at    java.lang.**strong text**ClassLoader.loadClass(    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(    at com.google.android.gms.internal.bb.<init>(    at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.<init>(    at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.<init>(    at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.<init>(    at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.<init>(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:442)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:194)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
```

Comment: Do you have the google play project added as a library for your project?

Comment: yes google play project added

Comment: copy your error log please.

Comment: 11-22 21:35:22.666: E/Trace(3188): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ornek.ornekbanner/com.ornek.ornekbanner.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2063)

Comment: 11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)

Comment: 11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Comment: 11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)

Comment: 11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:262)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at com.ornek.ornekbanner.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)

Comment: 11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2027)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  ... 11 more
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)

Comment: 11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  ... 22 more
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.bb.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-22 21:35:22.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.<init>(Unknown Source)

Comment: I copied the error log

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33392069/277345

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the right xml namespace defined in your layout:

Thus, `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-32763440xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

In the manifest's application tag, don't forget to add:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" 
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>`

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Comment: All of these code writing.But it does not install the application device.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get you. Make sure you're using the latest version of the library and you've referenced it well and do a project clean

Comment: Thanks, I was sure that the latest versions. I'm putting everything back in again.