# Adding Admob ads force close

Tags: java, android, xml

I have some project and I want to add `Admob` ads in my application. But when I am run my application project in emulator, it show force close.

Here's some code.

activity_main.xml

```
 <SearchView android:id="@+id/search" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
  android:iconifiedByDefault="true" />

 <ExpandableListView
     android:id="@+id/expandableList"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/search" />

 <com.google.android.gms.ads.adView
     android:id="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@+id/expandableList"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
 SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener{

 private SearchView search;
 private mylistadapter listAdapter;
 private ExpandableListView myList;
 private ArrayList<continent> continentList = new ArrayList<continent>();
 private AdView adView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

 adView = new AdView(this);
 adView.setAdUnitId("pub-4521673227772580");
 adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
 RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
 layout.addView(adView);
```

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tesskian"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
[<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />]
      [<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />]

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
      <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
      </activity>
```

And here's the log chat.

```
01-13 09:57:39.581: D/AndroidRuntime(533): Shutting down VM
01-13 09:57:39.581: W/dalvikvm(533): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tesskian/com.example.tesskian.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.adView
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.adView
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.example.tesskian.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  ... 11 more
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.adView
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
01-13 09:57:39.591: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  ... 21 more
```

I have no idea to fix this. Can anyone help me how to fix this force close?

Comment: this may help (it's the same error as from your log): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930782/classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-com-google-android-gms-ads-adview

Comment: I don't undestand sir, I had follow the instruction but still force close