# Infamous "Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView", works on Mac, not on PC

Tags: android, eclipse, admob, adt

I have two different dev computers, a PC and a Mac Laptop. I frequently work on one, check into a private repo on BitBucket, and switch to another.

Recently I have been trying to add Ads to an Android application (my first) using adMob. I kept getting the "Error inflating class com.google.adroid.gms.ads.AdView" printed out in my LogCat when I try to run the app in the emulator.

I tried all the usual things found Googling:

1. Made sure that I imported a copy of the google-play-services-lib into my workspace.
2. Made sure my project referenced said library, and that the referenced library had a green tick next to it.
3. Made sure I had updated AndroidManifest.xml with required permissions, meta-data, and activity.
4. Made sure my activity .xml file is importing the the correct xmlns: xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Finally I imported the GoogleAdsSampleActivity example into my workspace, added the google-play-services_lib as a library, and added my ad_unit_id, and it still wouldn't work.

On a whim, I checked everything in, and switched to my Mac. Everything works fine. Going back to my PC, I can get it to run in Android Studio, just not in eclipse, my Mac and PC are both using the same version of Eclipse (4.4.1 Build Id: 20140925-1800) and ADT (23.0.4.1468518). I have tried re-installing eclipse, re-installing ADT, using an older version of Eclipse, and even turning it off and on again, but I keep getting the same error.

Has anyone seen this before? Any other suggestions on what else I can try?

Thanks

**Update**
As requested, here is the full stack trace:

```
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067): Process: com.google.android.gms.samples.ads, PID: 1067
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms.samples.ads/com.google.android.gms.samples.ads.BannerXmlActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at com.google.android.gms.samples.ads.BannerXmlActivity.onCreate(BannerXmlActivity.java:34)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     ... 11 more
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.gms.samples.ads-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms.samples.ads-1, /system/lib]]
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
01-19 14:28:26.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     ... 21 more
```

Additionally, I realized that my emulator was running Android API level 17, so I thought this was the problem. Strangely enough, even though all the system images were installed, it would not let me create an emulator that would run level 19. Upon further investigation, I found that Eclipse was pointing to a version of the SDK that I installed manually, presumably a couple (or few) years ago. I changed it to use the same SDK that Android Studio is using and can now create a level 19 emulator, but am still getting this same error.

Concerning the code, I have made no changes to the GoogleAdsSampleActivity sample other than adding my own ad_unit_id. That is the sample I ran to get the above error.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: It's not so much the code that would be useful here, but rather the rest of the error message.  What you are listing is relatively early in the report; what would be really useful is the last "Caused by".  Do make sure you have indicated the library dependence correctly in each case - ie, not by adding it to the Java build path, but by listing it in the project configuration screen. The two look confusingly similar, but one results in the library getting included in the apk, and the other in it being referenced to produce a seemingly successful build but not included to yield a successful run.

Comment: Are you getting this error message in the IDE or at runtime after deploying your app to your device?

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33392069/277345

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` in the Linear Layout tag, put it in  `<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView` tag. as shown below:

```html
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        />
```

**For further assistance visit this [Link](http://www.techcorns.com/2015/05/23/make-money-android-app-ads/)**