# ViewPager and AdMob together shows error

Tags: android, android-viewpager, admob

I am creating an application with `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` and AdMob.

My heap size is `-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m`

App will work if I use both separately, but integrated together I get:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/info.androidhive.imageslider-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/info.androidhive.imageslider-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

App properties
[image]

Comment: you have tou add the googleplayservice libraray project

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33392069/277345

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a dependency on Google Play Services (or at least the Admob portion of it). Your app doesn't include the Admob classes.

Comment: how to include dependencies? by checking Android Dependencies?

Comment: i could use admob successfully. issue is when i use Viewpager and adMob together.

Comment: It sounds like when you are using both together you are removing the Google Play Services library. Or something else you are doing is removing those classes from your APK.

Comment: yup.else it exeeds the heap space

Comment: If you remove the Google play Services library then you will *always* get a ClassNotFound on its classes. Try including the just GooglePlayServices-Ads library if you need to restrict the size of includes.

Comment: Or using Proguard to remove unused classes.