# Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.Adview (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I'm getting an error when I try to put AdMob ads in my Android App. I've already did it with Eclipse + ADT, but when I try with Android Studio, it's not working. I guess I have a poor understanding on how to configure the project in Android Studio. I'll put some details below:

Stack Trace Error:

```
10-17 23:57:05.910    2067-2067/com.nlpoomanual E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nlpoomanual, PID: 2067
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nlpoomanual/br.com.nlpoomanual.activity.AjudeNosActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.Adview
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.Adview
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at br.com.nlpoomanual.activity.AjudeNosActivity.onCreate(AjudeNosActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.Adview" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nlpoomanual-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at br.com.nlpoomanual.activity.AjudeNosActivity.onCreate(AjudeNosActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.Adview
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 25 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

AjudeNosActivity.java

```
package br.com.nlpoomanual.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import br.com.nlpoomanual.R;
import br.com.nlpoomanual.bean.Sugestao;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class AjudeNosActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Sugestao sugestao = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ajude_nos);
        AdView ajudeNosAdAview = (AdView) findViewById (R.id.ajudeNosAdView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
        ajudeNosAdAview.loadAd (adRequest);
    }


    /* Other methods that I believe that are unecessary to show...
     */
}
```

res/layout/ajude_nos.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.Adview
                android:id="@+id/ajudeNosAdView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7700319823577941/5947568710"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc_ajude_nos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/texto_comum"
                android:text="@string/desc_ajude_nos"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rg_ajude_nos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/pink"
                >
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_sugestao_produto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/rb_sugestao_produto"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:background="@color/background_white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_sugestao_componente"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/rb_sugestao_componente"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                    android:background="@color/background_white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_sugestao_termo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/rb_sugestao_termo"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                    android:background="@color/background_white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_comunique_erro"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/rb_comunique_erro"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                    android:background="@color/background_white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_outros"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/rb_outros"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                    android:background="@color/background_white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    />

            </RadioGroup>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt_proximo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bt_proximo"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
                android:background="@color/pink"
                android:textColor="@color/background_white"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nlpoomanual"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.nlpoomanual" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23"
        >
    </uses-sdk>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_afrogirl"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.TelaInicial"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SobreActivity"
            android:label="@string/sobre_titulo" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.AjudeNosActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_ajude_nos" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.DicionarioDeTermos"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dicionario_de_termos" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.DescricaoTermoActivity"
                  android:label="@string/dicionario"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.BuscaComponentesActivity"
                  android:label="@string/busca_componentes">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.TipoProdutoActivity"
                  android:label="@string/produtos_liberados"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.BuscaProdutosActivity"
                  android:label="@string/produtos_liberados"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.DescricaoProdutoActivity"
                  android:label="@string/produtos_liberados"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.MenuPrincipalActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.FotoProdutoActivity"
            android:label="@string/produtos_liberados"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


</manifest>
```

I guess these files should help understanding the problem.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: okay .Post your manifest please

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. It's already there.

Comment: Does anyone can help? Any suggestion? My Android Studio is asking for an update. This update can help?

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33392069/277345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the error by copying my application files to a BannerExample project from [Google](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/releases/tag/2.7). To make my app shows the ads, I changed specially the following files.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.nlpoomanual" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23"
        >
    </uses-sdk>

    <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_afrogirl"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.TelaInicial"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample.MyActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SobreActivity"
            android:label="@string/sobre_titulo" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.AjudeNosActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_ajude_nos" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.DicionarioDeTermos"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dicionario_de_termos" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.DescricaoTermoActivity"
            android:label="@string/dicionario"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.BuscaComponentesActivity"
            android:label="@string/busca_componentes">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.TipoProdutoActivity"
            android:label="@string/produtos_liberados"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.BuscaProdutosActivity"
            android:label="@string/produtos_liberados"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.DescricaoProdutoActivity"
            android:label="@string/produtos_liberados"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.MenuPrincipalActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.FotoProdutoActivity"
            android:label="@string/produtos_liberados"
            >
        </activity>
        <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ajude_nos.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activity.AjudeNosActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/ajudeNosAdView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7700319823577941/5947568710" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc_ajude_nos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/texto_comum"
                android:text="@string/desc_ajude_nos"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rg_ajude_nos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/pink"
                >
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_sugestao_produto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/rb_sugestao_produto"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:background="@color/background_white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_sugestao_componente"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/rb_sugestao_componente"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                    android:background="@color/background_white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_sugestao_termo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/rb_sugestao_termo"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                    android:background="@color/background_white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_comunique_erro"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/rb_comunique_erro"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                    android:background="@color/background_white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_outros"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/rb_outros"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                    android:background="@color/background_white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    />

            </RadioGroup>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt_proximo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bt_proximo"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
                android:background="@color/pink"
                android:textColor="@color/background_white"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
}
```