# Rendering issues com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I'm using android studio, after 2 days of search i can't resolve this,  i want to use AdView to my project i try a lot of things but i am still have this error
at design time on android studio.

For the moment the build.gradle file have

> android {
>       compileSdkVersion 21
>       buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
>       .... }
>
> dependencies {
>       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:6.5.87'
>    }

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.internal.cy$a
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:53)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:466)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClassFromJar(RenderClassLoader.java:93)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.loadClassFromModuleOrDependency(ProjectClassLoader.java:108)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.load(ProjectClassLoader.java:89)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:56)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:374)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:99)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:172)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:400)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:575)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:564)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:564)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:691)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:483)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Have you tried to install the newest version of android SDK Build Tools? Also, switching from compiler compliance level 1.6 to 1.7. I found this Stack overflow ticket. I hope it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930782/classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-com-google-android-gms-ads-adview

Comment: Yes I updated almost anything :) but nothing works. I haved 1.6 and changed to 1.8, when i tried to install 1.7 i couldn't do it because i was update to  1.8 first. But i am getting the same error. I also tried a MultiDex but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

6.5.87 is an extremely old version of the Mobile Ads SDK. I believe 8.4.0 is the current release; give that one a try.